Azure DevOps -exportArchive: exportOptionsPlist error for key "method": expected one of {}, but found app-store
I am trying to run a Azure DevOps Pipeline for Task Name: Xcode@5.
I keep getting following error: error: exportArchive: exportOptionsPlist error for key "method": expected one of {}, but found app-store

Xcode@5 task:

- task: Xcode@5
  inputs:
    actions: 'build'
    configuration: 'Release'
    sdk: 'iphoneos'
    xcWorkspacePath: 'AheLine.xcworkspace'
    scheme: 'AHELine.UI'
    packageApp: true
    useXcpretty: false
    teamId: "65R5MW3X38" 
    exportOptions: 'specify'
    exportTeamId: "65R5MW3X38"
    exportMethod: 'app-store' // replace the method with accurate one
    signingOption: 'manual'
    signingIdentity: '$(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY)'
    provisioningProfileUuid: '$(APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID)'
    args: '-verbose CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=No CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=No -allowProvisioningUpdates SKIP_INSTALL=YES'

Error I am receiving:
** ARCHIVE SUCCEEDED **


/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Clear _XcodeTaskExportOptions.plist
Unrecognized Type: 
File Doesn't Exist, Will Create: _XcodeTaskExportOptions.plist
Initializing Plist...
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Add teamID string 65R5MW3X38 _XcodeTaskExportOptions.plist
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Add method string app-store _XcodeTaskExportOptions.plist
/usr/bin/xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath /Users/runner/work/1/s/AHELine.UI.xcarchive -exportPath /Users/runner/work/1/s/output/iphoneos/Release -exportOptionsPlist _XcodeTaskExportOptions.plist
2024-11-06 10:03:47.879 xcodebuild[25675:83509] [MT] IDEDistribution: -[IDEDistributionLogging _createLoggingBundleAtPath:]: Created bundle at path "/var/folders/z0/m_s6x1rn5799ttl3khp8n86r0000gn/T/AHELine.UI_2024-11-06_10-03-47.872.xcdistributionlogs".
2024-11-06 10:03:48.078 xcodebuild[25675:83509] [MT] IDEDistribution: -[IDEDistributionMethodManager orderedDistributionMethodsForTask:archive:logAspect:]: Error = Error Domain=IDEDistributionMethodManagerErrorDomain Code=2 "Unknown Distribution Error" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unknown Distribution Error}
error: exportArchive: exportOptionsPlist error for key "method": expected one of {}, but found app-store

Error Domain=IDEFoundationErrorDomain Code=1 "exportOptionsPlist error for key "method": expected one of {}, but found app-store" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=exportOptionsPlist error for key "method": expected one of {}, but found app-store}

** EXPORT FAILED **


##[error]Error: The process '/usr/bin/xcodebuild' failed with exit code 70

=> Is it possible to fix this error?
Related question on xcodebuild tool: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32841300/xcodebuild-exportarchive-exportoptionsplist-error-for-key-method-expected-o
